# How to install google chrome extensions though Terminal

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, extension

I want to install chrome extensions in chrome browser through Terminal instead of doing in GUI. 
Is there any way to install the extensions from Terminal?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800696/how-install-crx-chrome-extension-via-command-line Related for Chromium: https://superuser.com/questions/528551/how-to-install-extensions-on-chromium-without-the-web-store

Answer (score 9):

Here is the script, you gonna need extension ids, they can be found in the address bar when you go to the details of the extension on the market or at `chrome://extensions`. The script will also install chrome if it is not installed, remove the middle part if that's not needed.

1. Save this script to the `install-chrome.sh` file:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   install_chrome_extension () {
     preferences_dir_path="/opt/google/chrome/extensions"
     pref_file_path="$preferences_dir_path/$1.json"
     upd_url="https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
     mkdir -p "$preferences_dir_path"
     echo "{" > "$pref_file_path"
     echo "  \"external_update_url\": \"$upd_url\"" >> "$pref_file_path"
     echo "}" >> "$pref_file_path"
     echo Added \""$pref_file_path"\" ["$2"]
   }

   if ! which "google-chrome" ; then
     wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub \
     | sudo apt-key add -
     echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' \
     | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
   else
     echo Chrome already installed
   fi

   install_chrome_extension "cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb" "adblock plus"
   install_chrome_extension "fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi" "react dev tools"
   install_chrome_extension "anmidgajdonkgmmilbccfefkfieajakd" "save pinned tabs"
   install_chrome_extension "dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb" "vimium"
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   sudo bash install-chrome.sh
   ```
3. Restart chrome.

More scripts at https://github.com/grabantot/scripts

Comment: You could simplify those three `echo`s greatly with `printf`: `printf '{\n  "external_update_url": "%s"\n}\n' "$upd_url" > "$pref_file_path"`

Comment: @grabantot Is there any way so that the startup page for adblocker can be avoided?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your sharing, I have a question, can the script install the plugins to a specific Google account? If I open 2 browsers, one is using account1, and the other is using account2, how does the script know in which browser the extensions should install?

Answer (score 1):

As in [Google Chrome Documentations](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/#preferences)

Alternative extension installation methods : Using a preferences JSON file

requirements:

- Extension's ID
- latest Google Chrome install

here a script example (run with root privileges):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# install extensions via terminal

# fill the array with the needed extensions 
# key=["extension_name"] value="extension_ID"

declare -A EXTlist=(
    ["google-translate"]="aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb"
    ["save-to-google-drive"]="gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne"
)
for i in "${!EXTlist[@]}"; do
    # echo "Key: $i value: ${EXTlist[$i]}"
    echo '{"external_update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"}' > /opt/google/chrome/extensions/${EXTlist[$i]}.json
done
```

- close and reopen chrome and you will find the chosen extensions on all profiles
- remember to use the flag `--no-first-run` if you want to avoid the extensions first run pop ups

Answer (score 0):

For Linux the extension get stored under : `/opt/google/chrome/extensions/`
For install a Chrome extension (unpacked), use this command in terminal;

`<path to chrome> --load-extension=<path to extension directory>`

Comment: Hi @Akhil thanks for your response, can you please give an example with the proper commands.

Because am unable to find /opt/google/chrome/extensions/