# How do I use command line to install the "GNOME Shell Integration" package?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, gnome-shell, chromium, chrome-extension

Via the [GNOME Shell Integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en) webpage, to activate this package, I need to click on the button "**Available on Chrome**".

I would like to install/active this [GNOME Shell Integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep?hl=en) package via the terminal command line. How can I do so?

Comment: According to [the wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) you need the command  `sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell`. Did you have a problem with it?

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes I have `sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell`. However, I still have to manually open the Gnome Shell Integration Webpage and manually click on the "Available on Chrome" button to install it.

Comment: "Gnome Shell Integration" is not a (Ubuntu) package per se, it's a Chrome/Chromium browser extension. There are [ways to install browser extensions manually via the command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/1063331/480481) (also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670021), but I feel installing through the browser is a lot easier.

Comment: @pomsky Can you explain the inner workings of the function `install_chrome_extension()` that is found in your cited link? How do I change it to reflect "GNOME Shell Integration" package?

Comment: @sun The example shows how to install 4 extensions (adblock plus et al.). You can do the same with the GNOME Shell Integration. The answer is pretty self-explanatory and detailed. You just need the extension id which can be obtained from the address bar of the extension details page (the link you have added to your question).